# Siesta iOS GET request with url parameters

Tags: ios, swift, siesta-swift

Is there a way to make a GET request in Siesta, while providing parameter, like http://example.com/api/list.json?myparam=1?

I tried with

```
myAPI.resource("list.json?myparam=1")
```

but the question mark gets escaped.

Then I tried with

```
myAPI.resource("list.json").request(.GET, urlEncoded:["myparam": "1"])
```

but it always fails with "The network connection was lost.", but all other requests succeed, so the message is wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for [`withParam`](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Classes/Resource.html#/s:FC6Siesta8Resource9withParamFS0_FTSSGSqSS__S0_):

```
myAPI.resource("list.json").withParam("myparam", "1")
```

The [`Service.resource(_:)`](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Classes/Service.html#/s:FC6Siesta7Service8resourceFS0_FSSCS_8Resource) method you are trying to use in your first example specifically avoids interpreting special characters as params (or anything except a path). From the docs:

> The path parameter is simply appended to baseURL’s path, and is never interpreted as a URL. Strings such as .., //, ?, and https: have no special meaning; they go directly into the resulting resource’s path, with escaping if necessary.

This is a security feature, meant to prevent user-submitted strings from bleeding into other parts of the URL.

The [`Resource.request(_:urlEncoded:)`](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Classes/Resource.html#/s:FC6Siesta8Resource7requestFS0_FTOS_13RequestMethod10urlEncodedGVSs10DictionarySSSS_15requestMutationFCSo19NSMutableURLRequestT__PS_7Request_) method in your second example is for passing parameters in a request body (i.e. with a POST or PUT), not for parameters in the query string.

Note that you can always use [Service.resource(absoluteURL:)](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Classes/Service.html#/s:FC6Siesta7Service8resourceFS0_FT11absoluteURLGSqCSo5NSURL__CS_8Resource) to construct a URL yourself if you want to bypass Siesta’s URL component isolation and escaping features.