# Siesta iOS GET request with MULTIPLE url parameters

Tags: ios, swift, siesta-swift

I'm trying to use Siesta for sending **POST** request with multiple url parameters.

The problem is even though the solution is presented  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276714/siesta-ios-get-request-with-url-parameters), it only shows example for a single parameter. So my question is, is there any other ways to add multiple parameters or should I just use the **`withParam()`** multiple times?

**E.g.** **`.withParam("myparam", "1").withParam("myparam2", "1").withParam("myparam3", "1")...`**

I'm asking because using **`withParam()`** multiple times kinda look messy although it works =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve answered your own question: `withParam` is chainable, and that is the correct way to add multiple params.

It’s quite possible to format it in a tidy way, as in this snippet [from the example project](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/blob/master/Examples/GithubBrowser/Source/API/GithubAPI.swift#L142-L145):

```
var activeRepositories: Resource {
    return service
        .resource("/search/repositories")
        .withParam("q", "stars:>0")
        .withParam("sort", "updated")
        .withParam("order", "desc")
}
```

I would welcome a [feature request](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/issues/new) for a flavor that takes a dictionary if you or others think that would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, appreciate it.